# Extracting func_get_args in PHP

Tags: php

I have functions:

```
function a()
{
     b(extract(func_get_args(),EXTR_PREFIX_ALL));
}
function b()
{
    foreach(func_get_args()as$arg)
        echo"$arg\n";
}
```

I want to call the following:

```
a("Foo","Bar");
```

I want the following result:

```
Foo
Bar
```

`var_dump(func_get_args());` returns:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(3) "Foo"
    [1]=> string(3) "Bar" 
}
```

While `var_dump(extract(func_get_args(),EXTR_PREFIX_ALL));` returns `NULL`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Read the manual: http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#refsect1-function.extract-returnvalues

Comment: Why are you calling `extract()`?  What are you trying to do?  What you expect your code to do?

Comment: I'm trying to pass an unspecified number of arguments into a function that is passed an unspecified number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extract()` takes the *keys* from an array and creates variables with those names (and their values).  I'm not sure why you are trying to use it here.

As you can see, when you call `a("Foo", "Bar")`, then `func_get_args()` will give you an array of those two elements.

If inside `a()`, you did:

```
foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){
    echo"$arg\n";
}
```

Then it would work.

If you want to pass those parameters to another function, then you can do:

```
function a(){
    call_user_func_array('b', func_get_args());
}
```

If you are using PHP 5.6+, then you can use the [`...` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list):

```
function a(...$args){
    b(...$args);
    // Or you can do:
    // b(...func_get_args());
}

function b(...$args){
    foreach($args as $arg){
        echo"$arg\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, not sure why I got downvoted so much, because the `...` operator is the coolest thing I have learned in a while. I'm accepting this in 3 minutes.

Comment: Yep, works perfectly! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `extract` receives an associative array, in order to be able to declare the variables in the current scope by using the key as the name and the value as the value, and `func_get_args` returns a simple array.

After double checking, you are missing the prefix:

```
b(extract(func_get_args(),EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "prefix"));
```

Comment: The flag `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` appends `prefix` to all keys in a simple array, or at least thats what the manpages claim.

Comment: @EvanHendler Just double-checked and you are right, but you are missing the prefix. I've edited mya answer.

Comment: OK, trying it out now. It's dumping `int(2)`.

Comment: Thats the result of extract, you now have in your scope $prefix_0 and $prefix_1 variables.

Comment: Nope, you won't be able to pass those variables as arguments. I was just trying to explain why extract was not working for you. You better check @RocketHazmat answer.